# Failed to compute dot product of torch.cuda.FloatTensor

Tags: pytorch

I used a GPU to compute the dot product of the output of neural networks and a `torch.cuda.FloatTensor` (both of them are stored in GPU) but got an error saying:

```
TypeError: dot received an invalid combination of arguments - got (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) but expected (torch.FloatTensor tensor).
```

the codes are like

```
p = torch.exp(vector.dot(ht))
```

here vector is a torch FloatTensor and ht is the output of neural networks.

I've struggled with these things for days but still got no idea. Thanks in advance for any possible solution!

Comment: if my answer helped you to solve your problem, you can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

What does the following error message mean?

> TypeError: dot received an invalid combination of arguments - got (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) but expected (torch.FloatTensor tensor).

It means dot function expected **cpu** tensor but you are providing a **gpu (cuda)** tensor.

---

So, how to solve the problem of your code?

```
p = torch.exp(vector.dot(ht))
```

As you mentioned `vector` is a FloatTensor, so `ht` should be a FloatTensor as well but `ht` is a `cuda.FloatTensor` (because, your neural network model is in gpu memory).

So, you should convert `vector` to cuda.FloatTensor by doing the following.

```
vector = vector.cuda()
```

OR, you can convert the `cuda.FloatTensor` to cpu tensor by doing the following. Please note, `.cpu()` method is not applicable for [Variable](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/autograd.html?highlight=torch%20autograd#torch.autograd.Variable). In that case, you can use `.data.cpu()`.

```
ht = ht.cpu()
```

It should solve your problem.